# Boostrap JS - Nav-list tree not working correctly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Stumped on this one. I'm basically tying to make a nav list that will dynamically populate based on a variable that I've populated earlier in the script. Right now it's showing the parent items, but not the children. I know that the children are there, as the console outputs the names just fine.

The html body is this:

```
<div class="well" style="width:100%; padding: 8px 0;" id="header">

</div>
```

Really basic, just a place to put things.

the JS looks like this.

```
    $('#header').append('<ul class="nav nav-list">');
    for (var i in groupedtemplates) {
        $('#header').append('<label class="tree-toggler nav-header">' + i + '</label>');
        $('#header').append('<ul class="nav nav-list tree">');
        for (var j in groupedtemplates[i]) {
            console.log(groupedtemplates[i][j].attributes.im_name.value);
            $('header').append('<li><a href="#">' + groupedtemplates[i][j].attributes.im_name.value + '</a></li>');
        }
        $('#header').append('</ul>');
    }
    $('#header').append('</ul>');
```

I have to be missing something really obvious here. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: @anpsmn He doesn't add the closing tags for <ul> until after he's appended the <li> tags. It shouldn't be affecting anything.

Comment: @jwang Oh yes, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('header').append('<li><a href="#">' + groupedtemplates[i][j].attributes.im_name.value + '</a></li>');` probably should start with `$('#header')` instead.

Comment: *headdesk*

Yeah. That did it. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.